# Как наложить текст на картинку в html?

Tags: html, текст, img

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>
     Наука.ру - главная
    </title>
    <body>
        <style>
         h1{text-align:center;}
            h3{text-align:center;}
        </style>
        <img src = "https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg">
     <h1>Космоинфо</h1>
        <h3>Погрузись в космос вместе с нами!</h3>
        <h2><pre><a href = "http://www.astronews.ru">Новости</a>    <a href = "https://www.gismeteo.ru">Вопросы</a>   <a href = "file:///home/danila/program.html">Основная</a></pre></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

надо, чтобы  и  отображались прямо на картинке, а не под ней.

Comment: Или вариант что был предложен или воспользуйтесь position: absolute что бы поместить блок поверх другого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>
     Наука.ру - главная
    </title>
    <body>
        <style>
         h1{text-align:center;color:white;}
            h3{text-align:center;color:white;}
            body{background-image:url("https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg");}
        </style>
        
     <h1>Космоинфо</h1>
        <h3>Погрузись в космос вместе с нами!</h3>
        <h2><pre><a href = "http://www.astronews.ru">Новости</a>    <a href = "https://www.gismeteo.ru">Вопросы</a>   <a href = "file:///home/danila/program.html">Основная</a></pre></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй задать как фоновое изображение через CSS/SASS.

В .sass:

```
.image{
    background: url('image/image1.png');
    width: 320px;
    height: 280px; //размер условный
}
```

В HTML-документе:

```
<div class="image">
      <p>Текст Текст Текст</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1, с использованием `position: absolute`

```css
.container {
position: relative;
}
.container img {
position: absolute;
}
.container p{
color: #fff;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg" alt="">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, nulla? </p> 
</div>
```

Вариант 2, с использованием `background-image` (нужно знать размеры блока)

```css
.bg {
background: url('https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg') center center no-repeat;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
.bg span {
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, rerum.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    place-items: end center;
    }
.container img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.container p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 10px 20px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <img alt=""
            src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2022-04/1651167780_8-phonoteka-org-p-oboi-krasivoe-nebo-krasivo-9.jpg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Accusamus, fugiat. A, ipsum architecto sit nihil minus tenetur
            mollitia sequi est nostrum laudantium praesentium doloremque
            blanditiis recusandae, dolorum assumenda sed qui perspiciatis
            dolores? Quidem, itaque suscipit rerum, cupiditate delectus
            nesciunt dignissimos vel, odio corporis exercitationem facere
            nihil modi ducimus quas fugit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]